# How wrong is the following in predicate logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

If $P(x,y)$ means that $x$ is perpendicular to $y$. And $Q(x,y)$ means that $x$ is parallel to $y$, how wrong is the following written in predicate logic:

Every $x$ is perpendicular to $y$.
In predicate: "$\forall x, \forall y \in P(x,y)$"

There exists $y$ that is parallel to $x$. In predicate: "For $x$ there $\exists y\in Q(x,y)$"

I know that the upper aren't totally correct. My question is how wrong are they?

Comment: I don't know much about predicate logic, but isn't any given statement either true or false? What do you mean by *how* wrong it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every $x$ is perpendicular to $y.$
> In predicate: "$\forall x, \forall y \in P(x,y)$"

Literally: $∀x\:P(x,y).$ Here, the variable $y$ appears to be free.

(On the other hand, “Every $x$ is perpendicular to every $y”$ translates as $∀x∀y\:P(x,y).\,)$

Your suggestion just reads as “For each $(x,y)$ couple for which $P$ is true...”.

Both $P(a,b)$ and $(a,b){\in}P$ mean that $(a,b)$ satisfies $P(x,y).$

> There exists $y$ that is parallel to $x.$
> In predicate: "For $x$ there $\exists y\in Q(x,y)$"

Literally: $∃y\:Q(y,x).$

Comment: 'Here, the variable y appears to be a free" - Free variables are very unnatural though, aren't they? So one would rather write $\forall_x\forall_y P(x,y)$, wouldn't one?

Comment: @Filippo The first paragraph offers a faithful translation. (For example, a specification of $y$ may have preceded the given open formula.) On the other hand, the parenthetical paragraph second-guesses the author’s intent the same way as you.

Comment: @filipo your suggestion says every $x$ is perpendicular to every $y$ which makes perpendicularity a universal relation, in other words, everything is perpendicular to every thing. That's not what OP is asking.

Answer (score 1):

It's VERY wrong. It doesn't parse:

$$P, Q \subseteq S^2$$ which means $P$ and $Q$ are sets of ordered pair, therefore, their elements are of the form: $(a,b)$ and not $a$.

You can do this instead:

$$\forall x, \exists y P(x,y)$$ which says every $x$ is perpendicular to some $y$ without using elementhood.